# AIX pthread_create failure with EAGAIN. WLM class limits on threads?

Tags: pthreads, aix

The AIX man page for pthread_create documents the following reasons for an EAGAIN pthread_create failure:

```
       EAGAIN
            If WLM is running, the limit on the number of threads in the class is reached.
       EAGAIN
            The limit on the number of threads per process has been reached.
```

I'm seeing this in test code that starts 300 threads.  The curious thing is that I can create a test program with up to 2400 threads (although I have to reduce the default stack size to avoid ENOMEM) and I don't appear to hit any sort of threads per process limit, nor a WLM limit.

Since it doesn't appear to be the AIX threads per process limit that I am hitting, I'm wondering about other AIX sources of EAGAIN, or how WLM is configured for a specific process.  Our product does have WLM support, and I'm wondering if this test code accidentally configures itself as part of a WLM class, and what the mechanism to do this is?

Update:

It appears that the EAGAIN that I am getting is some undocumented pthread_create error condition and not WLM, since I see:

```
# wlmcntrl -q
1495-054 WLM is stopped
```

I also found that the ps command can be used to query what WLM class a process is associated with, as in

```
# ps -m -o THREAD,class -p 1040410
    USER     PID    PPID       TID ST  CP PRI SC    WCHAN        F     TT BND COMMAND         CLASS
 peeterj 1040410 2318428         - A    1  60  3 f1000602d5c19bb0   200801 pts/19   - /vbs/engn/sqo/t Unclassified
...
```

which again rules out WLM as a source of the EAGAIN.